# Regression functions of random variables

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, independence, conditional-expectation

Let $Y=a(X-b)^3+\epsilon$ where $\epsilon \sim N(0,\theta^2)$ is independent of $X$.

I know that the conventional regression function of $Y$ given $X=x$ is expressed as

$$f(x)=\mathbb{E}[Y|X=x]$$

What other ways can this regression functions be expressed as?

Namely, is $f(x)=a(x-b)^3$ also a valid regression function of $Y$ given $X=x$ ?

Comment: Your question is tautological: the two expressions you give for $f$ are equivalent.  That makes it difficult to determine what an answer ought to look like.  Could you clarify?

Comment: Sorry if the question is ambiguous @whuber. What I'm looking for is different ways to express $f(x)$ of $Y$ given $X=x$, and as per your comment, $\mathbb{E}[Y|X=x]≡a(x-b)^3$ is the same right? How about $f(x)=a+bx$ or $f(x)=3a(x-b)^2$ are these valid regression functions in this context? I'm new to this and am very curious about alternatives ways to express regression functions. Thanks!

Comment: I simply don't understand the thrust of your questions.  Literally any function can be a regression function.  Moreover, you already know $f(x)=a+bx$ is valid, as thousands of posts here on [tag:regression] will attest.  How to *express* a function is a huge subject, perhaps best addressed on a mathematics site.

Comment: Agreed @whuber. I will try my best to post more detailed or rather specific questions. I'm currently struggling with some canonical link functions which I will post separately perhaps you could lend me a helping hand there :)

Comment: Not to mention that I find Cross Validated more user-friendly in comparison to the other Stack Exchange websites where I would get immediate downvotes, I'm just trying to learn and improve myself :(

Comment: Both are good to hear.